# How to convert a string containing newline characters to multiline yaml

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have a string similar to the following:

```
test_string = "This is a multiple line string \n  
containing new line characters. \n  
Another new line."
```

I'm trying to use the to_yaml function to convert it to a multi-line yaml string but it automatically escapes the new line characters.

```
test_string.to_yaml
```

outputs:

```
=> "--- ! This is a multiple line string \\ncontaining new line characters.
 \\nAnother new line."
```

How do you create a string that contains `"\n"` and parse it into yaml?

EDIT:
As it turns out if you place a space before the "\n" the to_yaml function will escape the new line. The following string solved the problem:

```
test_string = "This is a multiple line string\n 
containing new line characters.\n 
Another new line."
```

Comment: I suspect you are using `p` or `inspect` to display the YAML?

Answer (score 2):

YAML treats an empty line (two consecutive line breaks) as being equivalent to \n.
from http://yaml.org/spec/history/2001-08-01.html

Had the same problem and finally found out solution:
s.replaceAll("\n", "**\n\n**");

Answer (score 1):

Where is this string coming from? If that was real Ruby code then the string would contain pairs of linefeed characters, not the two characters `\n`.

Inside double quotes `\n` is converted to a single linefeed character, so together with the linefeed at the end of the lines you would have two of them after each line. But `to_yaml` is seeing a backslash (which it escapes with a second backslash) followed by an `n` which is passed through verbatim.

There isn't a unique way of representing a string in YAML. `String#to_yaml` (or `YAML.dump`) generates the single-quoted *flow style* of string data unless the data contains characters that must be represented with double-quotes. Newlines are represented by a blank line in the YAML data.

This short program demonstrates.

```
require 'yaml'

puts "aa\nbb\n".to_yaml
```

**output**

```
--- ! 'aa

  bb

'
```